# How to set the default ARM processor state for kernel code?

Tags: arm

For the ARM processor supports both ARM and Thumb-2 state (instruction set), how to set which state to run kernel mode code, such as the kernel code for interrupt and system call.

Comment: Usually, it always defaults to **ARM**, unless the CPU only supports **Thumb**.  Ie, the Cortex-M series.  There might be some CP15 register on some specific CPUs to support this, but there definitely is no generic **ARM** mechanism.

Comment: Linux has CONFIG_THUMB2_KERNEL to set which instruction set to build the kernel as, when the configured target(s) support Thumb-2. The entry point is however always ARM state if the processor supports ARM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the v7 architecture*, bit 30 of the `SCTLR` determines whether exceptions are taken in ARM or Thumb state, which defaults to ARM on reset unless an external signal says otherwise. For v6 and earlier, exceptions are always taken in ARM state.

In the context of actually writing an OS, if you wanted to write exception handlers in Thumb in a backwards-compatible way I imagine you could also simply use an ARM interworking branch from the exception vector to the handler code itself - I'm no expert, though, so I can't say for sure there's no nasty pitfalls to this.

*and the in-between oddity that is the 1156

Comment: That sounds as correct as you can get for interrupts...  I just found the ArmV7 bit30 of the SCTLR.  Of course, for the Cortex-M series, it is always Thumb.  UnixSmurf has the API expectations for jumping/booting the initial Linux image.

Comment: Thanks. Will the state be transferred to ARM mode automatically when Thumb mode is interrupted if SCTLR indicates interrupts are taken in ARM state?

Comment: @Thomson Indeed - on an `SVC`, abort, interrupt, etc. the return address and SPSR are stashed, the CPSR is set to the appropriate mode _and instruction set_, and the PC is set to the relevant exception vector address and continues from there. Returning from the exception will then restore Thumb state via the SPSR. The ARM ARM explains exception entry much more clearly than I can, so check that for more details.